# Позитивный просмотр назад

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

```php
$str = "$24.56";
preg_match("(?<=\$)[0-9.]+", $str, $matches);
```

Скрипт должен взять цену без "$".

Comment: И назад смотреть зачем?

Comment: `^\$\d+.?\d+$`.

Comment: Изучаю эту тему, поэтому хотел понять, почему этот код не работает

Comment: Ваш вариант же дает явные ошибки, вы их не видите ? https://ideone.com/or1JoE А вот так https://ideone.com/feXXFe работает. А все от того, что вы не заключили регулярку в косые, кроме того задали ее в двойных кавычках, которые по особому понимают обратную косую, в итоге ее надо повторять дважды ...

Comment: Спасибо огромное!